# Devise lockable and custom strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am developing a custom strategy for LDAP authentication, and I have implemented the `valid?` and `authenticate!` methods as per http://kyan.com/blog/2013/10/11/devise-authentication-strategies and this Devise [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Authenticate-via-LDAP). My custom strategy works by itself.

I also want to use the [Lockable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable) module (and other Devise modules), but they seem to work only when [Database_Authenticatable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable) is also present. I have been reading the Devise source code, but I do not understand how Lockable is able to find the user (resource) in order to increment the :failed_attempts count. How do I pass the user record or resource to Lockable using my custom strategy?

My custom strategy is below. I am using Devise 3.5 and Rails 4.2

```
require 'net/ldap'
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
   class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable


  def valid?
    params[:user] && login.present? && password.present?
  end

  def authenticate!

    resource = mapping.to.find_for_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])

    if params[:user]
      begin
        ldap = Net::LDAP.new
        ldap.auth(my_ldap_service, my_ldap_service_password)
        ldap.encryption(:simple_tls)
        ldap.base = "base_here"
        ldap.host = my_ldap_host
        ldap.port = "636"
        result_attrs = ["employeenumber", "givenname", "sn", "mail", "department"] 

        result = ldap.bind_as(base: "base_here", filter: "(mail=#{login})", attributes: result_attrs, password: password, time: 3) 


        if result
          #valid ldap credentials
          user = get_user_from_database(result)
          if user
            success!(user)
          else
            fail!(:invalid_login)
          end

        else 
          fail!(:invalid_login)
        end

      rescue => e
        Rails.logger.error e.message
        fail!(:invalid_login)
      end

    end
  end

  def login
    params[:user][:email]
  end

  def password
    params[:user][:password]
  end

end
end
end
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Lavika see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [devise_custom_authenticatable](https://github.com/AMekss/devise_custom_authenticatable) in combination with the resources posted on the original question. For lockable to work,  database_authenticable must be present. Toni's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39567022/1486761) above should work if you have control over LDAP, which I did not when I posed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory should take care of a lockable feature. By using LDAP in your custom strategy, you move responsibility for the feature from your application to LDAP/Active Directory. Lockable should prevent a villain from brute-forcing access to your application. If Active Directory had no restrictions on this, he could simply run his attack directly against it and in case of success use the credentials in your application.

You should however enable your application to display error messages returned by the remote server like "Too many retries, try again in 5 minutes".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to call the `validate` method which is part of Authenticatable class you inherit from. The `validate` method calls the `valid_for_authentication?` method from the lockable module which then takes care of incrementing the attempts and lock the account.

In database_authenticatable this is solved [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb#L13) by using `valid_password?` which returns a boolean. In your case you would need to add a `validate(resource) { false }` in the case `bind_as` doesn't return a result.

The fixed full `authenticate!` method would look like the following

```
def authenticate!

    resource = mapping.to.find_for_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])

    if params[:user]
      begin
        ldap = Net::LDAP.new
        ldap.auth(my_ldap_service, my_ldap_service_password)
        ldap.encryption(:simple_tls)
        ldap.base = "base_here"
        ldap.host = my_ldap_host
        ldap.port = "636"
        result_attrs = ["employeenumber", "givenname", "sn", "mail", "department"] 

        result = ldap.bind_as(base: "base_here", filter: "(mail=#{login})", attributes: result_attrs, password: password, time: 3) 


        if result
          #valid ldap credentials
          user = get_user_from_database(result)
          if user
            success!(user)
          else
            fail!(:invalid_login)
          end

        else
          # no result -> wrong password
          validate(resource) { false }
          fail!(:invalid_login)
        end

      rescue => e
        Rails.logger.error e.message
        fail!(:invalid_login)
      end

    end
  end
```